# Oracle SQL display flag status as Y / null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to join 2 tables and display the FLAG STATUS based on availability of data in each of the tables.

Sample Data Sets

```
TABLE_A  |  TABLE_B
-------- | ----------
ENO      |    ENO
----     |  ----
100      |   100
101      |   101
102      |
```

What would be the oracle SQL logic to get result like

| ENO | A_FLAG | B_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Y | Y |
| 101 | Y | Y |
| 102 | Y | null |

Answer (score 0):

Use `full join` and conditional logic:

```
select eno,
       (case when a.eno is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) as a_flag,
       (case when b.eno is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) as b_flag
from a full join
     b
     using (eno);
```

This version assumes that there are no duplicates in the data, because duplicates are not mentioned in your question.  If you have duplicates, then you want something similar with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a typical demonstration of `OUTER JOIN`, where a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will suffice to use, *while using `FULL JOIN` is also possible*, when more populated table(`A`) is stated on the left hand side , along with `NVL2()` function which is an extension of the `NVL()` function with different options based on whether a `NULL` value exists such as

```
SELECT A.eno, NVL2(A.eno,'Y',A.eno) AS A_flag, NVL2(B.eno,'Y',B.eno) AS B_flag 
  FROM table_A A
  LEFT JOIN table_B B
    ON A.eno = B.eno
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b52ff7ba8115bbf31239cd3217fd46ce)</kbd>